# How make a GET request inside a loop using async

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, get

I'm having trouble getting get requests to run within a loop I have. The code is essentially this:

```
function getRequest(param){
   //Get request... then I save the response to a JSON file using fs.writeFile()
   //...
}
function run(){
   var arr = ['fee', 'foo', 'faa'];
   while(I need to update this for the duration of the program){
      arr.forEach((val) => {
         getRequest(val);
      }
   }
}
```

The get request won't go through because the loop won't wait for it to actually request. I've read some potential solutions using async functions, but could not get them to work. Any suggestions? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `getRequest` returns a `Promise`, you can do `Promise.all`. This also means that each individual request doesn't depend on any of the other responses. They can all run individually.

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Example:

```js
function getRequest(param){
   //Get request... then I save the response to a JSON file using fs.writeFile()
   //...
}
function run(){
   var arr = ['fee', 'foo', 'faa'];
   const promises = [];
   while(I need to update this for the duration of the program){
      arr.forEach((val) => {
         promises.push(getRequest(val));
      }
   }
   return promises;
}

const promises = run(); // Array of Promises
Promise.all(promises).then( response => {
  // ... 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Returning a promise in the getRequest method worked and then calling it in the run method worked as well - I tested them by just writing `const promises = run(); Promise.all(promises).then( response => {});` like you said. 
This worked... until I put it in a while loop that loops through every minute, updating the values. Do you know why that would be the case?
Just to be more clear, here's the code I used for the while loop: `while (true) {
 const promises = run();
 Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log('HELLO');
 });
}`

Comment: Nevermind, I got it figured out by using setInterval instead of a while loop...

Comment: I would not recommend using `setInterval` in a production-like scenario. Please remember to upvote/mark as answer

Comment: Why do you say that? I'm just curious. And yes, sorry I forgot to mark as answer. It wouldn't let me upvote because I'm a new member.

Comment: If you use setInterval, you are making a huge assumption that your wait (interval) time is enough time for the request to complete. You won't ever get this perfect so you are essentially slowing your application down due to poor design. `Promise.all` is definitely the way to go here. There's very little use case for `setInterval` so I would try and not use it.

Comment: Oh, I understand... But I am using Promise.all() inside my setInterval, so that should be ok. And even so, my interval is a minute, which is more than enough time to process the request. I think it should be ok because this project is just for my own use.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this as well

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

If you scroll to the bottom of the page, there is an example with api calls as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll keep this in mind for future use...